# Flutter can''t send sms using fluttersms

Tags: flutter, dart, sms

I'm trying to send sms after my app scanned a qrcode that contains a phone number.
I'm using FlutterSMS package for this but it seems doesn't work as supposed to do, it is not sending the sms. any help?

```
  void _sendSMS(String message, List<String> recipents) async {
    String _result =
        await FlutterSms.sendSMS(message: message, recipients: recipents)
            .catchError((onError) {
      print(onError);
    });
    print(_result);
  }

  Future _scan() async {
    String barcode = await scanner.scan();
    List data = barcode.split("|");
    String id = data[0];
    String phoneNumber = data[1];
    String message = "Halo! Pakaian anda sudah selesai di proses, silahkan ambil di gerai kami -LaundryKu";

    setState(() {
      this.id = id;
      this.barcode = barcode;
      this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    });
    _sendSMS(message, data[1]);
  }
```

Comment: try changing `_sendSMS(message, data[1]);` to `_sendSMS(message, [data[1]]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brother there is little mistake

**second argument is List**

```
_sendSMS(message, recipents);
```

**So you need to Add you Contact Number to List**

```
List<String> recipents = new List();
recipents.add(data[1].toString());

/// then the Msg in Variable

String message = "This is a test message!";
```

**Final pass both variable as parameters in function**

```
_sendSMS(message, recipents);
```

Finally you are Done ;)